# Can you test a model in ember without using ds?

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js

I'm getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: DS is not defined
```

Which is understandable considering I'm not using DS. Just wondering if I can run a model test without using DS. It looks like the test helper moduleForModel works with DS as a default, can I alter this method or replace it with something which will work?

Here's what my model looks like:

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({
   accounts: null,
   isaccountProductsOpen: false,
   ...
}
```